# What causes body temperature to rise drastically after being injured?

Tags: body-temperature, ankle, dizziness, sweat, sprain-strain-twist

I recently changed companies and started using a train for transport. In that time, I've sprained my ankle twice because of all the dreaded stairs at the train stations.

Each time this happened, my body temperature suddenly increased drastically, to the point that sweat starts dripping from me.

What is the cause and reason behind this sudden increase in temperature?

I've read that body temperature usually drops when severe injuries are experienced, but as painful as a sprained ankle is, I guess it doesn't meet that level of severity?

**EDIT:** I remember spraining my ankle far more severely in the past, and the same thing happened but I also became very dizzy soon after and I felt lightheaded for an hour or so. Does the dizziness perhaps mean nerve damage? And is it related to the increasing body temperature?

Comment: I'm betting you never measured your body temperature.

Comment: Not after experiencing injuries no, so I don't know exactly how much it increases, but it's evident that it does increase.

Comment: Your body temperature doesn't rise. Sweat doesn't necessarily indicate higher body temp. It also occurs as a response to cardiac problems and vagal responses. The vagal response probably explains what you're asking about.